# Passing data between views with parse.com?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to attach the following to a table view within a xamrian ios application. I have the code executing and pulling down the information, but I don't no how to populate the table view and pass the information along to the row clicked handle,. so that I can pass the information to the detail view. If somene could advice that be great.

```
// User's location
var userGeoPoint = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Get("locationGeo");
// Create a query for places
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("clinics");
//Interested in locations near user.
query = query.WhereNear("locationGeo", userGeoPoint);
// Limit what could be a lot of points.
query = query.Limit(10);
// Final list of nearby places
var placeObjects = await query.FindAsync();
```

Comment: Xamarin has an extensive [walkthrough](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/) on working with Table Views - have you read it?  As is, your question is too broad to be easily answered here.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin made a great walkthrough for working with tableviews.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/